# Should Angular components and services always avoid using setInterval (or rxjs timer)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, karma-jasmine, zone.js

I have some Components and Services that perform operations periodically in the background -- refreshing data, updating the displayed date/time, etc.  I originally wrote these features using `setInterval`. Now, I'm going back to add unit tests.  I spent *way* too long trying to figure out why my tests weren't working -- turns out that `fixture.whenStable()` will never resolve if the component under test (or any of its dependencies!) create an interval.  I tried switching from `setInterval` to rxjs `interval` / `timer`, but those have the same problem.

The advice given on [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697656/testing-angular2-components-that-use-setinterval-or-settimeout) is to put actual `setInterval` calls inside a dedicated "interval service", then mock out the service with something `tick`-able when writing tests.  I don't love the idea of changing my (working!) code to accommodate testing, if I can help it, but I think I really need `whenStable` to work.  Among other things, the Angular Material `TestbedHarnessEnvironment` uses it under the hood, so as far as I can tell, any component that includes an interval can't use Material harnesses.

My question is: as of late 2020, do I have any better options?  Is there a way to write `waitForAsync`-style tests for Components or Services that include an actual interval?  Or is there a better pattern I can use for my Component design, maybe some interval replacement that's integrated with existing Zone.js testing patches?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar (not identical) problem, which I solved as follows: in the test code, right after invoking `fixture.detectChanges()`, I stopped my timers (by unsubscribing). The only change in the tested code is to expose the unsubscribe code with a public function, for example:

```js
stopTimers() {
  this.intervalSubs?.unsubscribe();
}
```

Then in your test code:

```js
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
component.stopTimers();
```

Comment: I had forgotten about this question.  I never did come up with a better solution.  In some cases, I was able to use `whenStable` by mocking out a dependency on a service that uses timers (of course the mock doesn't need them), and in others I just avoided `whenStable` and relied on manually `tick`-ing, with a `discardPeriodicTasks` at the end of a test.  I never did adopt `TestbedHarnessEnvironment`...